# Api Routing in .net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I am new to .net core and I want to set a MapRoute to my api.
I config endpoint in startup.cs like

```
app.UseEndPoints(endpoints=>{
    endpoints.MapController("defaultApi","v1/{controller="cont"}/{action}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapController("defaultNonActionApi","v1/{controller="cont"}/{id?}")l
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");
});
```

and in controller.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class contController:ControllerBase{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(){}
}
```

The config in useEndpoints is useless, if I goto https://localhost:port/v1/cont it return a 404 and if i goto https://localhost:port/cont it can return an expected result.

It seems like the RouteAttribute override the config in useEndpoints but I can't remove RouteAttribute for an ApiController.

I know change `Route("[controller]")` to `Route("v1/[controller]")` can solve this problem, but what I want is something more global that can be configured in startup.cs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo like below:

1.Create a custom `MvcOptionsExtensions`:

```
public static class MvcOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, IRouteTemplateProvider routeAttribute)
    {
        opts.Conventions.Add(new RoutePrefixConvention(routeAttribute));
    }

    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, string prefix)
    {
        opts.UseGeneralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute(prefix));
    }
}

public class RoutePrefixConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    private readonly AttributeRouteModel _routePrefix;

    public RoutePrefixConvention(IRouteTemplateProvider route)
    {
        _routePrefix = new AttributeRouteModel(route);
    }

    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        foreach (var selector in application.Controllers.SelectMany(c => c.Selectors))
        {
            if (selector.AttributeRouteModel != null)
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(_routePrefix, selector.AttributeRouteModel);
            }
            else
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = _routePrefix;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.Register in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(o => { o.UseGeneralRoutePrefix("v1"); });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

3.Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class contController:ControllerBase{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(){}
}
```

Comment: It work well, thank you. But I have a question if i want to set both v1 and v2 in one solution, how should i config this prefix.